# I'm stuck with my list need push into right direction

Tags: java, list

This is my output of list:

```
/help_page/1 80 visits
/contact 89 visits
/home 78 visits
/about/2 90 visits
/index 82 visits
/about 171 visits
```

Now I need to sort this order and display by most visits like this:

```
/about 171 visits
/about/2 90 visits
/contact 89 visits
/index 82 visits
/help_page/1 80 visits
/home 78 visits
```

How can I achieve this in java? I have tried collections.sort() by that sort the list by alphabetically.

This is how I'm adding data into my list:

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String e:File.getPageList() ) {
        list.add(e + " " + File.TotalPages(e) + " visits");     
    }
```

File.getPageList() -> This method I created to get data from file and store into list.

File.TotalPages(e) -> This method calculates how many visits had particular page.
thanks

Comment: We dont know how your list data actually looks like ...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your work, and we can help you.

Comment: Instead of [`Collections.sort(List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-), you probably need to use [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: @GhostCat  I have showed you the output of my data so you can see how my data looks like.

Comment: There are a myriad of ways how this output could come to existence. You did not tell us what kind of objects you have in your list. Raw strings, data objects,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the file list right before you loop on it:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> fileList = File.getPageList();

// sort the fileList using File::TotalPages as key extractor for the comperator
fileList.sort(Comparator.comparing(File::TotalPages).reversed());

// use the sorted list for building the result:
for(String e:fileList) {
    list.add(e + " " + File.TotalPages(e) + " visits");     
}
```

I'm assuming `File.TotalPages` is not that complex becaus it is invoked multiple times per file.

Comment: thanks this is what i was looking for. It does sort it but in ascending order now i have to only add few more lines to revers the list :) thanks

Comment: @marcellio lines? I edited my answer to reverse the resulting order :)

Comment: Don't know, this looks like a new question. I recommend you provide a [mcve] there.